# Prove $e - s_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\frac{1}{(n+3)!}+...$ with $s_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

This is in my university textbook:

"$s_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$  ,   $n=1,2,...$.

The diﬀerence between $e$ and $s_n$ is given by:

$e - s_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\frac{1}{(n+3)!}+...$
"

This is not an exercise (the result is "given" like that) but I wonder how this difference can be calculated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I misread the book. It was in fact:
$s_n= 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + ... + \frac{1}{n!}$. This is not $s_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$ as I've written.

Comment: probably some confusion -- $s_n$ is probably the sum where $i$ ranges from 0 to $n$ (not to $\infty$)

Comment: As written, $s_n$ does not depend on $n$. It shoud be $s_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n 1/k!$. Since $e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} s_n$ the formula is obvious. There is not "explicit formula" for $e-s_n$.

Comment: My bad, You're right. I delete this question.

Comment: I can't delete it myself since it was answered, well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power series for $e^x$ is $$\sum_{n\ge0}\frac {x^n}{n!}.$$

Thus $e=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac 1{n!}$.

So, setting $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac 1{k!}$, we get $$e-s_n=\frac 1{(n+1)!}+\frac 1{(n+2)!}+\dots\, .$$

Comment: Thanks! In fact, as the comment under my post, it was a confusion of my part, sorry! This question should probably be deleted.